# Can you wash your hands completely after Chatzos on Tisha B'Av?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tisha-bav

One of the restrictions of Tisha B'Av is to only wash your hands until the knuckles. Is this restriction relaxed after Chatzos on Tisha B'Av? (sources please)

Comment: AFAIK there's no rule to only wash hands until the knuckles. The restriction is on washing any part of the body whatsoever. In certain instances (as on waking in the morning AFAIK, but CYLOR) the restriction is relaxed so one may wash until the knuckles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rabbi Shimon Eider in his "Summary of the Halochos of the Three Weeks" Lakewood, 5738 - 1978, says that washing, amongst other issurim, is prohibited the whole day (section V, G, 5). 
Only sitting on a bench above three tefachim, smoking, and work are allowed after noon (see in the sefer for details about work) and of course CYLOR.

Answer (score 3):

The 5 Inuyim (afflictions: eating & drinking, washing, etc.) are Rabbinically prohibited the whole day. There are other customs, such as not sitting on a chair, etc. and these are only customary until noon.